# Home button is not shown in action bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

This is first time i make a new apps since the time Action Bar was enabled in android 2.x.x by using android support ver7. Today i just install Android Studio (Because eclipse is no longer official tools for android development) and using it to make my apps. I notice that Home button is not show on the action bar when i run the app.

I already have these line in my code :

```
    mainActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mainActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);
    mainActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mainActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mainActionBar.setDisplayOptions(DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME| DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE| DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

But Home button is not display on the corner of the action bar.
Then i try too add these line:

```
    mainActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mainActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

The icon launcher is display but i can press on it.

Is there anybody can help me to solve it ? In my older apps, I used ActionbarSherlock and everything worked fine.
Here is the code in my older apps:

```
    _action = getSupportActionBar();
    _action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);
    _action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    _action.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    _action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Hope this Helps !

Comment: Can you improve your answer by saying why this works?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in your layout.

Let's say it has id "toolbar". Then in activity, fetch it and add your preferred settings.

```
    // onCreate method of activity:
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I dont want to use tool bar and never use it before. 
Do you have any suggestion to solve it without use toolbar ?

Comment: No - I don't have a workaround hack solution to replace the 5 lines of code I provided.